# Create SortedMap with Custom Compartor<Map.Entry>

Tags: java, comparator, sortedmap

I tried several things it appears `TreeMap` supports only sorting by keys. I attempted to work around it by code I found online but, it gave me `StackOverflowError` error. Why do I need the ability to compare by `Map.Entry` specifically. One is to compare by values, another is to compare values by a custom comparator such as shuffling or reverse order.

Also intended behavior is once this map is constructed any object added to the sorted map will use the comparator every time it gets added. The tutorials online use `LinkedHashMap` and converting into an array and then it gets stuck in that set order adding anything to that object will not keep the comparator ordering

```java
public static <K, V> SortedMap<K, V> sort(Map<K, V> map, Comparator c)
{
    TreeMap<K, V> ordered = new TreeMap<K, V>(c);
    if(c instanceof ComparatorValue)
        ((ComparatorValue)c).map = ordered;
    ordered.putAll(map);
    return ordered;
}
```

the comparator class

```java
public SortedMap map;
public ComparatorValue(SortedMap instance)
{
    this.map = instance;
}

@Override
public int compare(Object key1, Object key2) 
{
    Comparable val1 = (Comparable) this.map.get(key1);
    Comparable val2 = (Comparable) this.map.get(key2);
    if(val1 == val2)
        return 1;
    return val1.compareTo(val2); 
}
```

the error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
at jml.evilnotch.lib.simple.ComparatorValue.compare(ComparatorValue.java:17)
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the only issue, but `if(val1 == val2) return 1;` looks wrong. You shouldn't be using ==, and you should return 0 if they are equal, not 1.

Comment: I will save you time. [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--)

Comment: Also, don't use raw types `public SortedMap map`.

Comment: I just tried

  Map map = new HashMap();
  map.put("a", 1);
  map.put("b", -1);
  map.put("c", -2);
  TreeMap sorted = new TreeMap(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
  sorted.putAll(map);
  System.out.println(sorted);

and it did
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry

Comment: @nullsector76 Did you forget to escape the code in the comment just now or are you really using a raw-type map?

Comment: I forgot with the comparator